# Error using surf X, Y, Z, and C cannot be complex

Tags: matlab, 3d, plot

I get this error when i try to run the code below "Error using surf (line 75)
X, Y, Z, and C cannot be complex"

```
           Cx=1/10;
           Cy=1/25;

           [x,y]=meshgrid(2:0.2:20,2:0.2:20);
           G=1+sqrt(1-Cx^2*y^2);        

           F=2*G*(Cx*x^2+Cy*y^2)-Cx*Cy^2*(x^2+y^2)*y^2;

           z=F./(G*(G+(G^2-Cx*F)));


           surf(x,y,z,'facecolor','red',...
           'edgecolor','none',...
           'facelighting','phong');
            set(gcf, 'Renderer', 'ZBuffer')
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your `z` is complex (because your `G` is). Like the error says, you can't use `surf` with complex values